# How to display saved custom value in Editable Select in MVC Asp.net using JQuery Editable Select plugin?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using MVC5, Razor and C#

I have a traditional MVC dropdownlist.

```
   @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Car, (SelectList)ViewBag.CarSelectList, " -- Please Select --")
```

I want convert this into an editable dropdown, which I have done using the JQuery Editable Select plugin, see: [JQuery Editable Select WebPage](http://www.jqueryscript.net/form/jQuery-Plugin-For-Custom-Filterable-Select-Box-Editable-Select.html) using:

```
$(function () {
    $("#Car").editableSelect();
});
```

This all works fine. However when I type in a custom car that is not in the SelectList, it gets saved away, but when I refresh the edit page, the dropdown does not show the custom car ie "KitCar1". I suspect this is to do with the fact that this "KitCar1" is not in the select list and therefore cannot be matched. However how can I display "KitCar1" in the editable drop when I redisplay the page.

The only idea I have had is to show "Model.Car" in a seperate read-only "div" which works, but its is not a great solution.

Thoughts appreciated.

**EDIT 1:**

I did find a solution whereby I added the saved value as a new "SelectItem" into the "SelectList" within the "Get Action". This then produced the dropdown with the correct values.

Comment: That's probably because the context has not refreshed.

Comment: What values comes from EF after you refresh the edit page

Comment: To better understand, can you please clarify: when you say `when I type in a custom car that is not in the SelectList, it gets saved away`. Does this mean that the option you typed gets inserted into the dropdown box?

Comment: When you refresh your page, you are re-creating the select, so... have you checked if 'KitCar1' is included in your ViewBag.CarSelectList?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you need some sort of data persistence, and this can be done through your model. Every time you add an item to the drop down list, you need to add the item to some sort of database.

I suggest using AJAX to add these items to your model.

You should have a method in your controller that posts items to your model:

```
public void AddCarsToModel (string[] cars)
{
        List<Car> carNames = new List<Car>();

        foreach (Car car in cars)
        {
            carNames.Add(
            new Car
            {
              CarName = car
            });
        }

        try
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
}
```

and AJAX in your jQuery that posts to the method in your view:

```
$('#Cars').editableSelect({
  onCreate: function () {

      var carsArray = [];
      //for every car added to the dop down list, append it to the array

$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            traditional: true,
            url: "@Url.Action("AddCarsToModel", "Controller")",
            data: { cars: carsArray },
        success: function () {
            alert("Success!");
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            if (debug) {
                alert(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
                alert(textStatus);
                alert(errorThrown);
            }
        }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

When you type a custom car it gets saved away in select control. This will stay until the page reloaded.

When you refresh the page DropDown control is reset with data coming from the server. And your custom editable DropDown is built again using that DropDown option list.

So if want to keep that newly added custom car, you will have to save that new custom car to server. Specifically into your DB.

**Ajax** is a good option for that.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up adding the saved value as a new selectItem in the SelectList using Insert(). This all works fine now.